# What does this line of perl code mean?

Tags: perl, module, mason

I have a perl mason file and one of the lines looks like this:

```
$result = PI::Membership::Service->cancel(name => $name)
```

What exactly does that mean?  Is it calling another module? Is it object oriented perl code?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is calling (invoking) the subroutine `PI::Membership::Service::cancel` with three arguments.

1. `"PI::Membership::Service"`
2. `"name"`
3. `$name`

Given normal naming conventions, this is calling a subroutine called `cancel` in the package `PI::Membership::Service`, defined in a file named `PI/Membership/Service.pm` somewhere along your `@INC` path (there are many abnormal naming conventions, however, so there is no guarantee you will find such a file). And if the `PI::Membership::Service` package (class) inherits from one or more other packages, the `cancel` subroutine might actually be defined in one of those packages.

More details in [`perlobj`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlobj).

Comment: So, given normal naming conventions, what file would this be calling?

Comment: @JoeyFranklin — PI/Membership/Service.pm, as it says in the answer.

Comment: While defining items in the namespace PI::Membership::Service with a file under one of your library directories named something like PI/Membership/Service.pm would not be uncommon, there are no guarantees.  You should look to the source code for `use` or `require` statements.

Comment: This answer assumes that `PI::Membership::Service` does not inherit the `cancel` method. It could be defined in a parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `$result` is a `Pi::Membership::Service` object, it's not really an object oriented call because it's neither creating or manipulating an object. An object oriented call would look like this:

```
my $obj = Foo::Bar->new;   #Creating an object of class `Foo::Bar`
$obj->Baz                  #Calling method "Baz" on object "$obj";
```

It looks like this is an object style call to access a subroutine that's in another package and has not been *exported*.

To understand what's really going on, you must know about *namespaces*. Perl uses *namespaces*. Most of the time you might not be aware of it because you are using the default *namespace* of `main`. Namespaces are needed because you could end up (especially in pre-4.x versions of Perl) function and variable name collisions. Here's a program I have written in the old Perl 3.x style:

```
require "fribulate.pl";
$value = 4.5;
$new_value = fribulate($value);
print "Fribulated Value = $new_value  Original value = $value\n";
```

And here's my `fribulate.pl` program:

```
sub fribulate {
    my $param = shift;
    $value = $param * 2;
    return $value * 6;
}
1;
```

When I run my program, I get:

```
 Fribulated Value = 54. Original Value = 9
```

Wait? Wasn't it originally 4.5? The `fribulate.pl` program affected my `$value` because it is also using a variable called `$value`. To get around this, Perl created the `package` command that creates a new namespace:

```
package Fribulate;
sub fribulate {
    my $param = shift;
    $value = $param * 2;
    return $value * 3.1416;
}
1;
```

Now, the `fribulate.pl` program is not in *namespace* `main`, but in *namespace* `Fribulate`. Thus, the `$value` variable used in `fribulate.pl` isn't the same as my `$value` variable.

However, I can access a variable in another namespace if I prepend the namespace on it:

```
require "fribulate.pl";
$value = 4.5;
$new_value = fribulate($value);
print "Fribulated Value = $new_value  Original value = $value\n";

# Printing the value of $value from frimbulate.pl:
print "And in fribulate.pl, it's using $Fribulate::value\n";
```

You would have seen this if you used [File:Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html). To access the full name of a file, you use `$File::Find::name`. To access the file's directory, you use `$File::Find::dir`. The namespace `File::Find` is being prepended to the `$dir` and `$name` variables in `File::Find`.

The problem with namespaces is that everything is now in the new namespace, including my `frimbulate` function in `frimbulate.pl`. Thus, my original program also has to prepend the namespace in front of the function in order to work:

```
require "fribulate.pl";
$value = 4.5;
$new_value = Frimbulate::fribulate($value);
print "Fribulated Value = $new_value  Original value = $value\n";
```

To get around this issue, you did a little fancy footwork in the `frimbulate.pl` program:

```
Package Frimbulate;

require Exporter;
@EXPORT = qw(frimbulate);

sub fribulate {
    my $param = shift;
    $value = $param * 2;
    return $value * 3.1416;
}
1;
```

The `Exporter` package sprinkles magic pixie dust<sup>1</sup> on the functions in `@EXPORT` and makes them available into the `main` namespace -- the default namespace where all of your stuff resides. Thus, modules like [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) and [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) use `Exporter` to allow you to access their respective `copy` and `basename` subroutines without prepending the package name in front of them.

This is now considered bad style because you could end up overwriting other subroutines with the same name without any warning. In the new style of writing modules, you no longer automatically export all of your functions in the `@EXPORT` array. You'll notice this in [File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) which doesn't automatically export its functions into the `main` namespace without our explicitly requesting it. Instead, you put them in `@EXPORT_OK` which requires users to ask them to be pushed into the namespace:

#### Frimbulate Package

```
Package Frimbulate;

require Exporter;
@EXPORT_OK = qw(frimbulate); #You have to request the frimbulate subroutine

sub fribulate {
    my $param = shift;
    $value = $param * 2;
    return $value * 3.1416;
}
1;
```

#### My Program:

```
# Now I have to ask that the frimbulate subroutine be import into my main namespace
require "fribulate.pl" qw(frimbulate);
$value = 4.5;
$new_value = fribulate($value);
print "Fribulated Value = $new_value  Original value = $value\n";
```

This should now give you enough background to read the [Perl Module](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod) documentation and quite possibly understand what's going on.  The Perlmod documentation covers namespaces, the symbol table, and even a bit about variable scope. It's contains a lot of information, and can be a bit intimidating without basic information.

---

<sup>1</sup> No pixies were harmed in use of the Exporter module. If you look at `Exporter.pm` which you can find with the `perldoc -l Exporter` command, you'll see that it's directly manipulating the symbol table.